# Detect leaf directories in Perl

Tags: find, directory, perl, recursive, darwin

For a Perl script I'm working on, I'm looking for a *fast* and *reliable* way to find all subdirectories (transitively) of a given directory which are leaves, i.e. those not having any subdirectories of their own. For example, given this hierarchy:

```
foo/
foo/bar/
foo/bar/baz
foo/you_fool
```

my hypothetical function, when called with `"foo"` as the argument, should return the list `("foo/bar/baz/", "foo/you_fool/")`.

Because this will clearly require `File::Find` or something equivalent, and that already does a `stat` system call for each file it finds, *fast* means not doing another `stat` on each file, although one extra `stat` on each *directory*, i.e. the value of `$File::Find::dir` is okay.

Because my main target system is Darwin aka MacOS, I unfortunately cannot use the `nlink` field of `struct stat`; it doesn't seem to be meaningful on that file system. I'm aware that on a "real Unix" file system I could just compare `nlink` to 2 for each directory.

If it matters, we may disregard symlinks, special files and all other oddities; the hierarchies I'll be searching are very clean and regular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
perl -MFile::Find -le '
  find(sub { 
         if (-d _) {
           undef $leaves{$File::Find::name};
           delete $leaves{$File::Find::dir};
         }
       }, ".");
  print for keys %leaves'
```

`undef` sets hash element for the current dir to an `undef` value, while `delete` deletes the hash element for the parent directory. So at the end the keys of the `%leaves` hash contain only the leaves.

With `-d _`, we're reusing the information from the `lstat()` that `File::Find` did on the current file, so no extra `lstat()` / `stat()` is performed. With `-d` alone, an extra `stat()` (not `lstat()`) would be performed, which means it would also return true for symlinks to directories.

While it works in my test, it may not be a valid and future-proof thing to do. The documentation says:

> [with "follow"] It is guaranteed that an *lstat* has been called before the
> user's "wanted()" function is called. This enables fast file
> checks involving "_". ***Note that this guarantee no longer holds
> if *follow* or *follow_fast* are not set***.

Doing `if (! -l && -d _)` may be safer, at the expense of an extra `lstat()` being performed for each file.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about `-d` and `lstat`.

Answer (score 0):

Just some thoughts. I'm not a perl maestro, so not sure what File::Find can do, so I turned to the shell 'find'.

```
find / -type d -print
```

prints out a list of directories starting from '/', so there's the basic list. I very much doubt you can improve on its speed in perl, though a C app just might manage. I suspect it would be wasted effort for miniscule benefits.

GNU find has an option '-printf' that accepts a '%h' flag to print out the parent directory. What you could do therefore is to -printf both the path %p and the parent path %h at the same time, then in perl split the parents off into a new list. You now have a list of paths that are not leaves, so remove those from the %p list, and you're done.

Sadly MacOS doesn't have the GNU find but a lesser version. You can install GNU find using 'brew', but it wouldn't be too hard to create the effect of %h from the %p lines in perl directly.

One last thing to note. Relying on linefeed termination of pathnames from a pipe or similar is known to be subject to error under some circumstances, hence GNU find and (I think) MacOS find both have a zero-terminate option for lines separated by \0 rather than \n. If you can use it, do so.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be much more straightforward than I thought, using a feature of `File::Find` that I had not known, or had forgotten. Here's the entire script (before I start adding code irrelevant to the question);

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;
use Cwd qw(realpath);

@main::leaves = ();

sub preprocess {
  our (@leaves);
  my @names = @_;
  my @subdirs = grep { $_ ne q(.) && $_ ne q(..) && -d } @names;
  push @leaves, $File::Find::dir unless @subdirs;
  return @subdirs;
}

sub wanted {
  # do nothing at all
}

sub find_leaves {
  my @roots = map { realpath($_) } @ARGV;
  find({ wanted => \&wanted, preprocess => \&preprocess }, @roots);
}

sub main {
  our (@leaves);
  @ARGV or push @ARGV, q(.);
  find_leaves();
  print $_, qq(\n) foreach (@leaves);
  # my $num_leaves = $#leaves + 1;
}

main();
__END__
```

Comment: Note that `-d` implies extra `stat()`s (not `lstat()`s, meaning you'll also have problems with symlinks to directories in leaves).